# Drag And Drop Without Containerlist

Tags: codenameone

I have been using ContainerList with drag and drop functionality in the past. Since ContainerList has been deprecated I am now trying to use something different. As recommended in the documentation I would like to use just a Container with BoxLayout in the y-axis.
However looking into that this seems to be rather difficult, too.

What I am trying to (re-)create ist a list of entries containing with labels and buttons which entries van be sorted by a longPointerPress followed by drag and drop.

In the past I managed to do this by heavily modifying the ContainerList and ContainerList.Entry classes.

But with a Container I cannot see how to do this at all.

As I see it this would involve:

- creation of a ListEntry component derived from Container and overriding de.sae.tryout.modules.dragdrop.DraggableContainer.getComponentAt(int, int) to always return this to intercept all of the pointer interactions and
- depending of its state passing through the pointer events to the child components if it is appropriate

Since this seems to me as an inadmissible trick the question: What is the recommended way to display such a sortable list of entries where each entry contains some labels and buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Since every entry would be a lead component to make it feel like a container list just using `setDraggable(true)` on the lead component and `setDropTarget(true)` on the parent will allow drag and drop.

Notice this won't have the same behavior as you have now with the long pointer press which might be a problem but might not. If this is a problem you can override the drag initialization behavior of the lead component to make it closer to the way it worked.

Comment: The entries of my list shall contain buttons and labels. If I make a label the leadComponent the buttons cannot be used since the label gets all the pointer events. If i make a button the leadComponent only this button fires and if other sibling components are tapped.
Your solution does not work for me.